# Difference between $p(x)$ and $p(x+2)$

Tags: polynomials

Suppose i have the following polynomial $$p(x)=\sqrt{7}(x-1/2)$$
What would be $$p(x+2)=?$$
I know it might be a simple question but i can not find the answer, any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried substituting $x$ by $x+2$ in $\sqrt{7}(x-1/2)$?

Comment: I actually did it. But i made a mistake and i thought what i was doing was wrong. I did it again and it was correct. I guess i asked a stupid question. But thank you anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $z$ we have $$p(z)=\sqrt{7}(z-1/2).$$ Thus when $z$ is $x+2$ we have $$p(x+2)=\sqrt{7}(x+2-1/2) =\sqrt{7}(x+3/2).$$